how do i track calories to lose weight
I am a 25 years old female about 5 ft and weigh about 75 kg. I lose weight but I am unable to maintain the weight I lost and I regain it faster. how can I lose and maintain my weight through calorie count?

How are achieving this weight loss? Do you exercise regularly / what kind of exercise? Do you follow any workout program / diet? Do you have any medical condition / take any medication that could interfere? Counting calories is only one factor for weight loss. Please [edit] the question to add details.

You really can't lose weight on a permanent basis just through calorie counting, because you aren't changing habits. As soon as you stop counting, extra calories come back into play and the weight comes back.
The first question to answer is - are you happy with the way you look? If yes, stop there and don't worry about it. If you are not happy with the way you look, is it a society problem? I.e., you aren't happy with the way you look because society says it's bad? Or are you genuinely unhappy with the way you look? If it's the former, forget society and be happy in your own skin. If its the latter, read on.
Calorie counting generally fails because you are aiming at an artificial target (weight), and as soon as that is achieved, you stop the things that got you there. Calorie counting works because it makes you think about everything you are eating, which generally makes you eat less as well as eat better foods. If you want a snack, you generally grab an apple and some peanut butter rather than chips and dip.
Learning what foods you like and are healthy, how to control appetite (Such as having a small bowl of soup before dinner), learning to eat slower and without distractions (studies have shown people eat more calories when watching tv or reading or otherwise distracted while eating), how to properly add exercise to a weekly routine. As soon as you change your habits and make healthy eating a normal instead of tracked activity, it will be easier.
Lastly, don't chase an arbitrary number on a scale. Use the mirror. If you are happy with what you see in the mirror and you are healthy, that's all that matters. Chasing an arbitrary number on a scale hardly ever works. Use the scale to monitor trends (such as weigh yourself every few days under the same conditions, and see if the number is trending up or down), and the mirror as your goal.
